# return a single html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get jQuery to return a html element exactly the way that `getElementById` does?

if I `console.log($('#container'))` I will get :

```
[<div id="container"></div>]
```

But the API I am interacting with obviously doesn't want that (an array) - it wants :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

I know I can achieve this with `$('#container').get(0)` and a few other ways, It just seems overkill - especially as I'm selecting an ID which will always be unique.

What am I missing guys?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `$('#container')[0]`

Comment: Why don't you just use getElementById?

Comment: In fact, I do not see a question here. You know more than you try to ask.

Comment: I know it seems an odd question! I am currently using `getElem...` but I have a few HTML nodes I'm accessing and just wondered if I could cut down on typing! haha!

Comment: To cut down on typing, define your own shortcut replacement function for `document.getElementByid()` like I've shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a single DOM element, then just use plain javascript:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("container");
```

jQuery selectors always create a jQuery object with an array of elements in it.  That's just the way it's designed.  If you want a single element, you either get the first element out of the jQuery object or you use a different tool.

From a jQuery object, you can get the first object either with:

```
$('#container').get(0)
```

or with:

```
$('#container')[0]
```

But, I would argue that both are more than you need if all you want is the single object that has an id.  Just use `document.getElementById()`.  If you want less typing, you could make your own short function:

```
function $$(id) {
    return(document.getElementById(id));
}

var obj = $$("container");
```

Comment: just a thing, should be "container" not "#container"

Comment: @Rodolfo - yes, I fixed the typo.

Comment: You should drop the `#` it will not work with plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks man. You answered my question with `jQuery selectors always create a jQuery object with an array of elements in it` - I was wondering if it could return a single element, to help me cut down on characters. :p

Comment: @user1036214 - Did you see the last part of my answer that makes for less typing?

Comment: I've just noticed it. That looks like the perfect solution. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using .html() it will return the html of the element your selecting see:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: That will return the contents of the element, not the element itself.